# ignoring Https SSL exception on iphone

Tags: iphone, objective-c, ssl

I have a self signed SSL certificate serving out my test enviroment.  I would like to do some testing connecting to the service from my iphone however, the SSL exception is causing an error.

Is there a way to ignore the SSL exception on the iPhone?

Edit:

I should have added a bit more detail, the answers below will work hoever if i can get it to work inside NSXMLParser that would be even better.

Answer (score 3):

If you're only testing, you can use the private `setAllowsAnyHTTPSCertificate:forHost:` method  on `NSURLRequest`. Otherwise, I'd recommend using the [ASIHTTPRequest](http://allseeing-i.com/ASIHTTPRequest) library which provides a great high-level API to the CFNetwork APIs, including the ability to use self-signed certificates. The method you're looking for is `setValidatesSecureCertificate:`.

Comment: Can that be called for multiple hosts? (Again, it's for quick testing only, and this is for a test-only host where I can't get a proper cert installed.)